Community Basemap Labels on top of other layers
I am trying to place the labels for the Community basemap on top of other layers in my map. With some basemaps, there is a reference layer that is added and you can place it at the top of the ToC and the labels will be placed on top of everything, but there isn't that option for the Community basemap. How can I do this?

You probably need to start by explaining what the "community basemap" is? It is not one of the standard basemaps that come packaged with ArcPro, well certainly not the UK version at least.

Unfortunately the Community basemap doesn't support a seperate reference layer. The basemaps that offer this fucntionality are:

Imagery with Labels
Terrain with Labels
Light Gray Canvas
Dark Gray Canvas
Oceans

